# Apple M2 - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

I have React Native project. Recently after some upgrade on system I noticed that the project is not built. It's on *macOS Ventura 13.3.1*, *Apple M2 Pro*. Xcode version is **14.3**. Cocoapods version is **1.12.1**.

I'm getting

> node: command not found Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code under RealmJS

I'm not sure after what this error started appearing, but I tried every solution internet offered, but none of them worked.

Most mentioned internet solutions:

1. Check `Run script only when installing` in *Targets -> Build Phases -> Start Packager*; *Targets -> Build Phases -> React Native code and images* and *Targets -> Build Phases -> Embedded pods frameworks*.
2. `arch -x86_64 pod deintegrate; pod install`
3. In *Build settings -> Excluded Architectures* add and delete `arm64`.
4. Make sure to have `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"` in *Pods -> Target Support Files -> Pods-THE_APP-Frameworks*.

Any new suggestions?

Comment: Try to downgrade Xcode to 14.2 using `xcodes` https://github.com/XcodesOrg/xcodes

Comment: Some native modules are not optimized to compile with M1+ architecture. Try to check if  target emulator is using Rosetta - https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/

Comment: @VasylNahuliak, I tried but doesn't work

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel, I tried but doesn't work

Comment: @EKOLX Did you manage to solve this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For everybody else who's struggling with this one, I managed to solve this by editing

> ${yourProject}node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh

and (in my case) removing the **nvm if statement** since I'm using nvm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

cd ios

pod cache clean --all

Pod clean

pod deintegrate

sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod repo update

arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: Does not work...